# How to write a custom row class (extends Zend_Db_Table_Row) for a Db_Table class in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db-table

I have separate db_table classes for **books**, **book_sections** and **users** (system end users). in **book table** has **columns** for **book_title**, **section_id**(book_section) , **data_entered_user_id**(who entered book info).

go to this url to see the image(I'm not allow to post images bacause I'm new to stackoverflow)
img685.imageshack.us/img685/9978/70932283.png

in the backend of the system I added a **form to edit existing book** (get book id from GET param and fill the relevant data to the form). form has elements for **book_title**, **book_section** and **data_entered_user**.

to get exciting book data to "edit book form" I **join book_section and user tables with book** table to get **book_section_name and username**(of data_entered_user: read only- display on side bar)

go to this url to see the image(I'm not allow to post images bacause I'm new to stackoverflow)
img155.imageshack.us/img155/2947/66239915.jpg

**In class App_Model_Book extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract**

```
public function getBookData($id){
     $select = $this->select();
    $select->setIntegrityCheck(false);
    $select->from('book', array('id','section_id','data_entered_user_id',...));
    $select->joinInner('section','book.section_id = section.id',array('section_name' =>'section.name' ));
    $select->joinInner(array('date_entered_user' => 'user'),'book.date_entered_user_id = date_entered_user.id',array('date_entered_user_name' =>'date_entered_user.user_name' ));
    $select->where("book.id = ?",$id);
    return $this->fetchRow($select);
}

public function updateBookData($id,$title,$section_id,...)
{
   $existingRow = $this->fetchRow($this->select()->where('id=?',$id));
   $existingRow->title = $title;
   $existingRow->section_id = $section_id;
   //....
   $existingRow->save();
}
```

**In Admin_BookController -> editAction()**

```
$editForm = new Admin_Form_EditBook();
$id = $this->_getParam('id', false);
$bookTable = new App_Model_Book();
$book_data = $bookTable ->getBookData($id);
//set values on form to print on form when edit book
$editForm->book_title->setValue($book_data->title);
$editForm->book_section->setValue($book_data->section_name);
//........
//If form data valid
if($this->getRequest()->isPost() && $editForm->isValid($_POST)){
$bookTable = new App_Model_Book();
$bookTable ->updateBookData(
$id,
//get data from submitted form
$editForm->getValue('title'),
//....
);
```

when editing an exsiting book

1. get data from getBookData() method on App_Model_Book class
2. If form data is valid after submiting edited data, save data with updateBookData() method on App_Model_Book class

> but I saw that if I created a **custom
>   Db_Table_Row(extends Zend_Db_Table_Row)
>   class for book table** with
>   book_section_name and
>   data_entered_user_name **I can use it
>   for get existing book data and save it
>   after editing** book data **without
>   creating new Book(db_table) class and without calling updateBookData() to save updated data**.But I don't know which **code I should write on custom
>   Db_Table_Row(extends Zend_Db_Table_Row)
>   class**.

I think you can understand my problem, in simple

> **how to write a custom db_table_row class to create a custom row with data
>   form 2 joined tables for a perticular db_table class ?**

I'm new to zend framewok and to stackoverflow. forgive me if you confused with my first question.

Thanks again.

Comment: Please, post your code. It will be more easy to provide you the best way if we can see exactly what you're doing. Without see it, the only thing I can think, is to use an ->update($data,'id =1') method instead of make an instance of the book again.

Comment: sorry, I'm new to zend framewok and to stackoverflow. I updated it with 2 images, but can't post it because I'm new to stackoverflow so I add urls. thanks again

Comment: The **One** and **Only** Tutorial for this is 
[here](http://mattmccormick.ca/2010/04/24/how-to-easily-create-models-and-table-relationships-in-zend-framework/)

Answer (score 3):

1) at your db_table class create field which contain row class, for example:

```
protected $_rowClass  = 'App_Model_Db_Books_Row';
```

and add reference map for parent tables:

```
protected $_referenceMap = array(
    'Section' => array(
        'columns'           => 'sectionId',
        'refTableClass'     => 'App_Model_Db_Sections',
        'refColumns'        => 'id'
    ),
    'User' => array(
        'columns'           => 'userId',
        'refTableClass'     => 'App_Model_Db_Users',
        'refColumns'        => 'id'
    )
);
```

2) at row class you must define variables for parent tables:

```
protected $section;
protected $user;
```

In such cases i create method called "load":

```
public function load()
{
    $this->section = $this->findParentRow('App_Model_Db_Sections');
    $this->user = $this->findParentRow('App_Model_Db_Users');
}
```

And in constructor i call this method:

```
public function __construct(array $config = array())
{
    parent::__construct($config);
    $this->load();
}
```

As a result after:

```
$book_data = $bookTable ->getBookData($id);
```

you can access data from reference table, for example:

```
$book_data->section->name = "Book Section";
$book_data->section->save();
```